# Why are microsoft .teamfundation.client version 9.0 not supporting version 1.0 methods?

Tags: tfs

- I am getting problem with `microsoft.teamfundation.client` version
  9.0.
- I had been using `microsoft .teamfundation.client` version 1.0
  intially.
- To support some other methods, I used
  `microsoft.teamfundation.client` version 9.0.

But only some methods in version 1.0 are supported in this 9.0 vesrion.

Can any body help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, can you reword your question a bit so it's clearer what the problem is? Are you saying that version 9.0 doesn't support some methods from the older version? If that's the case, then it's entirely possible those methods have been deprecated and subsequently removed in later versions; the documentation trail ought to give you a hint as to whether that's the case.

Comment: Methods are there but passing parameters are different.

for ex:

NetworkCredential creds = new NetworkCredential(AppSettings.Username, AppSettings.Password, AppSettings.Domain);
 TeamFoundationServer tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(AppSettings.TfsUrl,creds); this works fine with version 1.0


but same thing has problem with version 9.0 

 TeamFoundationServer tfs = TeamFoundationServerFactory.GetServer(AppSettings.TfsUrl,creds); 

here Getserver method is not accepting credsof type NetworkCredential  but expecting icredentialprovider but which has no implimentation.

Comment: Hi Rob,

Thank you, where can i find documentation regarding this.

Regards
Suneetha.